# Backbone.js toggle a popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Simple popover view that can be inserted into another view. On creation it is referenced to an view element of the parent view:

```
function(app) {

  var Popover = app.module();

  Popover.Views.Default = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'popover',
    initialize: function(options) {

      this.reference = options.reference;
      this.reference.bind('click', this.toggle());

      this.render();
    },
    beforeRender: function() {
      this.content = this.$el.find('.popover');
    }
    toggle: function() {
      console.log('toggle');
    }
  });

  // Required, return the module for AMD compliance.
  return Popover;
});
```

The reference is the element on which the popover will be set like:

```
Main.Views.Start = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: "main/start",
    serialize: function() {
      return { model: this.model };
    },        
    initialize: function() {
      this.popover = new Popover.Views.Default({
          reference: this.$el.find('.member')
      });
      this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
    },
    beforeRender: function(){
      this.insertView(this.popover);
    }
  });
```

The popover is displayed correctly, however when I click on `a.member` nothing happens. Besides I noticed that on page refresh the toggle method is fired and toggle appears in the log. Very strang. Any ideas why this happens? How do I connect link click in parent view with the toggle method of the popover?

When I log the reference:

```
[prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: undefined, selector: ".member", jquery: "2.0.0", constructor: function…]context: undefinedlength: 0prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]selector: ".member"__proto__: Object[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not binding correctly the event to the `reference`, try with:

```
this.reference.bind('click', this.toggle);
```

---

At the moment you are creating the `popover` object `$el` does not contain the `.member` element, your log shows an object with length equals to 0. Make sure that you are creating the `popover` after the creation of `member`, maybe after the `render` method.

Comment: Hm it does not bind, when I click the element nothing happens

Comment: This was just a typo, I posted the reference log in my question

Comment: Yes just realized that, so I need to create the Popover view after rendereing the parent view right?

Comment: @artworkadシ right, maybe after the `render` method once the parent view contains the `member` element

Comment: Ok thank you, add this to your question and it will be perfect